# How to convert individual lists into combined dataframes in R for bigdata?

Tags: r

Struck up with the analysis part, I had 2 lists with elements and I want to convert them into a combined data-frame.

I'm using R-4.0, Pandas don't have support.

```
v1 = c("0.669689430316622","0.529912995153638","0.503184463959419","0.388594892019547","0.282688877720632","-0.162915578083457","-0.173655153138899","-0.190133436716019","-0.201831577016519","-0.205355041002986","-0.213582932863881","-0.215741217780107","-0.222777891546275","-0.271801277739071","-0.274070525500782",
"-0.30020928621804","-0.300926692227094",   "-0.341620331728635","-0.345216578871688","-0.345358121903771","-0.35767778501432","-0.368606895779704","-0.374789816076096","-0.405664485454666","-0.41058487380805","-0.419727119059569","-0.422073424627699","-0.424488032321518","-0.451289352653048",
"-0.461484485131514","-0.46272591301108","-0.483283472084585","-0.488369131678979","-0.500932680625342","-0.511210919948069","-0.523481734400967","-0.539168686486807","-0.540656283188186","-0.541650313401483","-0.564565481836278","-0.589070995414538")
v2 = c("LOC117748635","syt1b","LOC117732005","LOC117745460","katna1","arid1aa","prrc2b","fam120c","wu:fc21g02","usp9","nrxn2b","cntn3b","LOC117743866","prrc2a","LOC117751129","tspan9a","hs6st1a","bcl11ba","kcna1b","LOC117745510","actr2a","slc8a3","tmem132e",
     "ipmkb","ptp4a1","cdc42ep4b","agap3","fam168a","ctdspl2b","yap1","LOC117733589","scarb2a","camta1a","LOC117728330","zbtb16a","trim71","mapk1","LOC117741824","pip5k1ca","foxo3a","LOC117747932")
```

Like

```
head(df)
V1                   V2
0.669689430316622" LOC117748635
```

Comment: do you need `data.frame(v1, v2)`

Comment: Sorry, I was literary confused.

Comment: I meant to construct the `data.frame` by passing the two vectors (assuming they are equal lengths)

Comment: Yes you're correct.